# IJCAD　一行文字の展開場所が原点になる

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

下記のコードにて文字記入をしているのですが、VerticalMode、HorizontalModeはコメントアウトしています。
コメントアウト時は問題ないのですが、有効にした場合、原点(0,0)に指定文字が展開されます。
位置合わせは、テキスト作成と同時にはできないのでしょうか？

```
Dim dbTxtTest As DBText = New DBText()

With dbTxtTest
    .Position = New Point3d(50, 260, 0)
    .Height = 2
    .TextString = "テスト"
    '.VerticalMode = TextVerticalMode.TextVerticalMid
    '.HorizontalMode = TextHorizontalMode.TextLeft
End With

modelBlkTblRec.AppendEntity(dbTxtTest)

trans.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(dbTxtTest, True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

位置合わせの後に、AlignmentPointプロパティで位置を指定してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

一行文字作成時に、水平と垂直の位置合わせフラグとともに
AlignmentPointのみ指定すれば、AlignmentPointからPointを計算してくれます。

既定の左・基準線位置合わせでは Point のみ指定します。
フィットと両端ぞろえでは Point と AlignmentPoint の両方を指定する必要があります。